# How to make ASP.Net Core Web API Identity return a 401 on unauthorized

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to get ASP.net core web api JSON Web Token authentication working properly. I've got to the point where I have successfully integrated IdentityServer4 with the app, and it is successfully processing logins based on ASP.net Core Identity.

However, whenever authentication fails, the API returns a 302 result trying to redirect the client to a login page. However, this is a pure Web API, there is no user pages, or anything that a user is supposed to directly interact with.

How can I get the system to return a 401 rather than trying to redirect to a login page?

The identity part of ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
       // ASP.net Identity
        var identityBackingStoreConnectionString = configuration["identity:backingStore"];

        services
            .AddIdentityWithMongoStoresUsingCustomTypes<MyApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
                identityBackingStoreConnectionString)
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddSingleton<IClientStore, MyIdentityStore>();

        // IdentityServer4
        services.AddIdentityServer().AddTemporarySigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(MyResourceStore.GetAllResources())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<MyApplicationUser>()
            .AddTemporarySigningCredential();
```

and the relevant (I think) part of Configure looks like this:

```
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ApiName = "myapi",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = async context => context.Response.StatusCode = 401
            }
        });

        app.UseMvc();
```

As you can see, I've tried overriding the OnAuthenticationFailed event, but to no avail.

Any suggestions as to how to get the system returning a 401 would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity server uses cookie authentication internally which converts 401 into 302.

I don't think you can make `app.UseIdentityServer()` and   `app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication()` live together because of it.

However you can easily find a workaround.

The best is to host identity server in separate application (e.g. identity server at *localhost:5000* and application at *localhost:5001*). It fits better the concept of open id connect and you can enjoy tons of examples at [official GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples)

Alternatively you can try placing Identity server and API at different subpaths like *localhost:5000/idsrv* and *localhost:5000/api* using `app.UseWhen`. For example

```
app.UseWhen(
    c => c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")), 
    branch => {
       branch.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
       {
           Authority = "http://localhost:5000/idsrv",
           RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
           ApiName = "myapi",
           AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
       } );
       branch.UseMvc();
   });

app.UseWhen(
    c => c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/idsrv")), 
    branch => {
       branch.UseIdentityServer();
       branch.UseMvc();
    } );
```

Again, this approach is more error-prone and I would rather consider separate applications.

Comment: I couldn't get the UseWhen approach to work, but separating the two components into separate systems worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!